# Dealing with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i don't understand this question:

A user of a WEB system, which runs on a J2EE application server with 3 GB of RAM receives the error message below into your browser to access certain system functionality.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Considering that the RAM of the server application is no more than 30% and the station user has a Windows operating system, consider the following actions.

1. Increasing the size of the page file station tester.
2. Change value of the parameter "-Xmx" JVM server.
3. Decrease the amount of recursive methods the system.

Which statements are valid?

Can someone please help!

Comment: Where did you get that question? It's very poorly written and difficult to understand.

Comment: in an assignment, i don't understand it at all!

Comment: The question is basically: you have a user on a windows workstation using his browser to load pages from a Java EE web server. The browser displays the error message "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". What should you do to fix the problem? 1. increase memory on the windows workstation of the user? 2. use the -Xmx option on the Java EE webserver to give this server more heap memory? 3. decrease the amount of recursive method calls in the Java code of the web application?

Answer (score 1):

2. Change value of the parameter "-Xmx" JVM server.